# How to pass a value from the Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

How can i pass a value from the jquery validation. I have an input box named clubCardNumber it should validate the length of the inputted value. If the length is equal to 10 the value passes to the hidden field named  else validated it if its null or empty if all validations are true then its a clubCard.

Here is how i implemented it on Javascript

```
 function validateClubCardNumber() {

    var varClubCardNumber = $('#clubCardNumber').val();     
    $('#phoneNumber').val("");
    var returnVal = true;

    if ((null == varClubCardNumber || '' == trim(varClubCardNumber)){
        return false;
    }
    if( varClubCardNumber.length < 10 ){
            return false;

    }else if( varClubCardNumber.length == 10 )  {
        //The Phone Number field should contains numbers only
        var pattern  = /^[0-9 -]*$/ ;
        var flag = pattern.test(trim(varClubCardNumber));
        if(flag == false){
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#phoneNumber').val(varClubCardNumber);
            returnVal = true;
        }
    }

    }
    return returnVal;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div >
   <label for="clubCardNumber" >Card or Phone Number:</label>
   <input id="clubCardNumber" name="clubCardNumber" type="text" placeholder="Card or Phone Number" value="" maxlength="20"/>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" value=""/>
```

Comment: and here's the html part 
 
   
`<div >
   <label for="clubCardNumber" >Card or Phone Number:</label>
   <input id="clubCardNumber" name="clubCardNumber" type="text" placeholder="Card or Phone Number" value="" maxlength="20"/>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" value=""/>`   Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to pass? If you would like to pass "redturnVal" to another function simply remove var from the front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code

```
if ((null == varClubCardNumber || '' == trim(varClubCardNumber)){
    return false;
}
```

**By**

```
if (!$.trim(varClubCardNumber){
    return false;
}
```

Read [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim)

**Full Code**

```
function validateClubCardNumber() {
    var varClubCardNumber = $.trim($('#clubCardNumber').val());
    $('#phoneNumber').val("");
    var returnVal = true;    
    if (varClubCardNumber || varClubCardNumber.length < 10){
        returnVal = false;
    }
    else if( varClubCardNumber.length == 10 )  {
        //The Phone Number field should contains numbers only
        var pattern  = /^[0-9-\s]*$/ ;
        var flag = pattern.test(varClubCardNumber);
        if(flag == false){
            returnVal = false;
        }else{
            $('#phoneNumber').val(varClubCardNumber);
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not that far off.  Taking from Rohan's post and a little more cleanup, this is what I came up with as a solution

```
function validateClubCardNumber() {
  var CARD_NUMBER_REGEX = /^[\d-\ ]+$/;
  var varClubCardNumber = $.trim($('#clubCardNumber').val());
  $('#phoneNumber').val("");
  if( varClubCardNumber && 
     (varClubCardNumber.length === 10) &&
     CARD_NUMBER_REGEX.test(varClubCardNumber)) {
       $('#phoneNumber').val(varClubCardNumber);
       return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I noticed that the only time you need to check the validation (with the regex) is if the length is right, so instead of the if elsif else structure, I tried to simply.

Answer (score 0):

am thinking if this would could work

```
$("#registrationForm").validate({
            rules: {
                clubCardNumber : {
                    required: {
                          function (element) {
                       var returnVal = true;    
    if (varClubCardNumber || varClubCardNumber.length < 10){
        returnVal = false;
    }
    else if( varClubCardNumber.length == 10 )  {
        //The Phone Number field should contains numbers only
        var pattern  = /^[0-9-\s]*$/ ;
        var flag = pattern.test(varClubCardNumber);
        if(flag == false){
            returnVal = false;
        }else{
            $('#phoneNumber').val(varClubCardNumber);
        }
    }
    return returnVal;}
                    },
```

sorry for the confusion guys. i wanted to put my JS validation on the required validation of JQ validation.